# Spring Integration AWS s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter stream from multiple s3 buckets

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am using XML based spring integration and use `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` to stream from a **single** s3 bucket.

We now have a requirement to stream from **two** s3 buckets.

So is it possible for `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` to stream from **multiple** buckets?

Or would I need to create a separate `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` for **each** s3 bucket?

This is my current set up for a single s3 bucket and it does work.

```
<int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter 
channel="s3Channel"
session-factory="s3SessionFactory" 
filter="acceptOnceFilter"
remote-directory-expression="'bucket-1'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up having **two** `s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter` as mentioned by **Artem Bilan** below.

However, for each inbound adapter, I had to **declare instances** of acceptOnceFilter and metadataStore separately.

This is because if I only had one instance of acceptOnceFilter and metadataStore and these were shared the the two inbound adapters, then some weird looping started happening.

**e.g.** When a file_1.csv arrived on **bucket-1** and got processed and then if you put the same file_1.csv on **bucket-2** then weird looping started happening. Don't know why! So I ended up creating acceptOnceFilter and metadataStore for each inbound adapter.

`

```
    <!-- ===================================================== -->
    <!-- Region 1 s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter setting -->
    <!-- ===================================================== -->

    <bean id="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>

    <bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
          class="org.springframework.integration.aws.support.filters.S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStore"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="streaming"/>
    </bean>

    <int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="s3Region1"
                                                  channel="s3Channel"
                                                  session-factory="s3SessionFactory"
                                                  filter="acceptOnceFilter"
                                                  remote-directory-expression="'${s3.bucketOne.name}'">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="s3Channel">
        <int:queue capacity="50"/>
    </int:channel>

    <!-- ===================================================== -->
    <!-- Region 2 s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter setting -->
    <!-- ===================================================== -->

    <bean id="metadataStoreRegion2" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>

    <bean id="acceptOnceFilterRegion2"
          class="org.springframework.integration.aws.support.filters.S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStoreRegion2"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="streaming"/>
    </bean>

    <int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="s3Region2"
                                                  channel="s3ChannelRegion2"
                                                  session-factory="s3SessionFactoryRegion2"
                                                  filter="acceptOnceFilterRegion2"
                                                  remote-directory-expression="'${s3.bucketTwo.name}'">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="s3ChannelRegion2">
        <int:queue capacity="50"/>
    </int:channel>
```

`

Comment: Would appreciate if someone from Spring can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the current implementation supports only a single `remote directory` to poll periodically. We really are working at this very moment to formalize such a solution as an out-of-the-box feature. Similar request has been reported for the (S)FTP support, especially when the target directory is not know in advance during configuration.

If that is not a big deal for your to configure several channel adapters for each for the directory, that would be great. You always can send messages from them to the same channel for processing.

Otherwise you can consider to loop the list of buckets via:

```
  <xsd:attribute name="remote-directory-expression" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Specify a SpEL expression which will be used to evaluate the directory
                path to where the files will be transferred
                (e.g., "headers.['remote_dir'] + '/myTransfers'" for outbound endpoints)
                There is no root object (message) for inbound endpoints
                (e.g., "@someBean.fetchDirectory");
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

in some bean.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update above. I ended up creating acceptOnceFilter and metadataStore for each inbound adapter as some weird looping started happening if I didn't have this.